# Noob shading advice. How do I shade like the referenced image?

Tags: materials, shaders

Noob question here ;)
I need to shade a human figure to look like the referenced image (White and blue-grey).
I would also deed to know if it's better to be done in EVEE or Cycles.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Reference image for material]

[image: Model I need to add shading]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Looks like rough metal to me.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly simple to achieve. You can make a shader like that using Layer Weight node and its facing output colored with a Color Ramp( <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>  and search in Shader Editor):

[image]

This is a shader that does not react to environment so it really doesn't matter much what engine you use for it. The choice of render engine would probably be dictated by other circumstances.